# Get nodes from a xml layout in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater

Using a layout template ex: **temp.xml** I'm creating a new View with LayoutInflater and I add that View to my MainActivity layout:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp, null, false);
mainActivLayout.addView(newView);
```

**teml.xml** has the following structure:

```
LinearLayout -> LinearLayout -> (two children) ImageView & TextView
```

How do I extract from the **newView** the `ImageView` and `TextView` elements so I can add Text and a Image to them ?

Do I have to TypeCast `newView` to Node or NodeList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findViewById()` on the `newView`

```
TextView textView = newView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview_id);
ImageView imageView = newView.findViewById(R.id.my_imageview_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an ID for both the `TextView` and `ImageView` in the `temp.xml` and after that you can use `newView.findViewById(VIEW_ID)` to get the instance of the `View`.